# Insert Dashes dynamically based on format

Tags: javascript, formatting

I would like insert dashes to ID based on another property.

In the property the user can include dashes anywhere. The IDs should display in the format given in the property.

For example:

property: `111-11-1111`
The ID should display like `123-11-1111`.

Something similar where we will add dashes from property:

```js
id.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "$1-$2-$3");
```

Comment: Please, update the question with your code. It's not clear, what you're working with.

Comment: loop through the characters of `property`. When it's `1`, append the next digit of the ID to the result.  When it's `-`, append `-` to the result.

Comment: Could you kindly provide me an example

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution. It splits the format string on dashes. Then uses the lengths of those substrings to pull substrings from the id. Then joins those with dashes.

```js
const mapID = (id, format) => {
  return format.split('-')
               .map((ones, idx, onesArray) => id.substr(onesArray.slice(0, idx).join('').length, ones.length))
               .join('-');
}

console.log(mapID("123456789", "111-11-1111"));
console.log(mapID("123456789", "1111-1-11-11"));
```